# does registry need to be changed to grant permission to a program?

Tags: debugging

i have made a game and it's self installer after the game is installed it runs only if it is installed on e drive or d drive not in the c drive that has my os
it says access denied
somebody told me that it needs permissions by making registry changes
is it so?
i know how make the changes 
but what changes do i make??

Edited to add the text from the answer made by the person who created the question:

i was writing to c:\programfiles\abess\ and the installer runs successfully the installed program does not run ,i am using windows 7 home and using administrator account

Comment: `c:\program files\` and anything under there will usually also be read-only during normal operation. Does your game try to write to any files? Or if it reads from any files, does it try to open them as read&write? You need to store any game data somewhere else than than the same directory as the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Is it trying to write any files to `C:\` on a Windows 7 (or possibly Vista) machine? If so, by default you won't have write permissions there (assuming the C: is the system drive). Make sure that your app writes any files to subdirectories of `C:\`, like `C:\Temp\` or similar.

I'm fairly certain that if it works on `D:` but not on `C:` it won't be a problem with the registry.

Answer (score 0):

i was writing to c:\programfiles\abess\
and the installer runs successfully the installed program does not run ,i am using windows 7 home and using administrator account 
after installing if the program is run as "run as administrator" it runs successfully
i am making the installer i can't be sure if on the other end user installs on c:\programfiles\ and gets frustrated when program does not run

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information, and delete this answer. Don't post comments/updates as answers.

Comment: how do i edit my question? it has only two options flag and link no edit